# Discord.py - Changing prefix with command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a command where an admin can change the prefix for commands (eg: instead of using "." they can change it to "-" and only "-" will work if they do) I'd be able to setup the permissions to make only admins able to use the command

I've looked around, through the docs & interwebs but haven't found anything and I haven't had any idea on how to do this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use the [`command_prefix`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix) argument for [`discord.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#bot) this accepts either a string *(meaning one bot wide prefix)* or a callable *(meaning a function that returns a prefix based on a condition)*.

Your condition relies on the invoking `message`. Therefore you can allow guilds to define their own prefixes. I'll use a dict as a simple example:

```
...

custom_prefixes = {}
#You'd need to have some sort of persistance here,
#possibly using the json module to save and load
#or a database
default_prefixes = ['.']

async def determine_prefix(bot, message):
    guild = message.guild
    #Only allow custom prefixs in guild
    if guild:
        return custom_prefixes.get(guild.id, default_prefixes)
    else:
        return default_prefixes

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = determine_prefix, ...)
bot.run()

@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def setprefix(self, ctx, *, prefixes=""):
    #You'd obviously need to do some error checking here
    #All I'm doing here is if prefixes is not passed then
    #set it to default 
    custom_prefixes[ctx.guild.id] = prefixes.split() or default_prefixes
    await ctx.send("Prefixes set!")
```

For a great example of this in use, refer to [Rapptz](https://github.com/Rapptz) *(the creator of discord.py)*'s very own [RoboDanny](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny) bot, he made it a public repo for educational purposes as an example. In specific, see [`prefix_callable`](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/blob/fd226cb16be6b1a69d5822a604a72d21cb6afba8/bot.py#L43) function, it's a more robust version of my `determine_prefix` example.

Comment: could you edit that to make it like it's in the main bot file & not a cog? I can't change it from cog to main since I haven't got the hang of cogs yet

Comment: The logic is there, just make the command however you're doing now I guess. Besides, take a look at RDanny bot for cog examples to help.

Comment: I followed the code above, but at the `command_prefix=` bit I get this error (my version of `command_prefix=` is: `command_prefix=determine_prefix, commands.when_mentioned`) the error is: `positional argument follows keyword argument` and it highlights (in red) the space between `determine_prefix` and `commands.when_mentioned`

Comment: Please see the docs. You're using `when_mentioned` wrong. See the docs for [`when_mentioned_or`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=when_mentioned#discord.ext.commands.when_mentioned_or)